# Facebook post IDs changed en masse today

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I collect data across several hundred Facebook accounts daily. To keep track of which posts I already have versus which ones are new, I use the post ID and only collect those with IDs I've not already stored (or update likes/shares/comment counts if I do already have them). I use the Graph API "posts" node

```
https://graph.facebook.com/(FB account name)/posts
```

I've already been doing this for over a year. However, in today's update, I noticed I had collected about 1000 times the number of  "new" posts that I usually collect (and checked my daily counts across the past few weeks to make sure), and that these new posts were distributed across the few hundred accounts I collect data from. On closer inspection, I discovered that it appears they're duplicates of posts I already had and that they were collected because their post IDs had changed (sometimes only by a digit, sometimes quite a lot). I can see both the original and duplicate post data in my database. Some of the posts are over a year old, and this happened across many accounts, so I think post updates being the culprit are out of the question.

An example is this set of post IDs from HyVee:

84150862796_10152725672357797 (new)

84150862796_10152725672477797 (original)

Oddly, both of these IDs work when using the graph explorer tool and seem to return the same post content.

I've never noticed such an event before and I don't think the code that collects the data has been changed in a long while. At the same time, I find no mention of this the phenomenon when searching for it, and I expect many people would be talking about it if post IDs suddenly changed, as a lot of things would break, I imagine. The account whose API key is being used to collect the posts has also not changed in any way.

Is this kind of thing unheard of? Are post IDs not intended for long-term tracking of posts? What could have caused this?

Comment: You are referring to receiving updates via webhooks specifically, right? Then you are likely experiencing this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220792561689292/

Comment: This is very similar, although in my case, it seems like the 2nd part of the ID is changing, not the first. With any luck, though, the same fix will apply...

Comment: Also I'm using polling rather than a webhook subscription